# Cleaning up a query that uses subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about making a SQL Server query more efficient.

I have a table with the following columns

```
ID          int
ValueDate   datetime
Value       float
```

I want to select rows for each ID starting from the date where the value is greater than zero.  This is the SQL I have come up with

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ValueDate, a.Value 
FROM MyTable a,
(SELECT ID, MIN(ValueDate) as VDate FROM MyTable WHERE Value > 0 GROUP BY ID) B
WHERE a.ID = b.ID and a.ValueDate >= b.VDate
```

This works but I wonder if there is another way to do this that would be more efficient.  I am particularly interested in looking at other forms because I am needing to replace a single table with a subquery.  I am worried that since the query would have the same subqueries twice that this will slow down execution.  Is there anyway to adjust the query so that the subquery is only run once.  The kicker to this is that the query needs to also run on Oracle and Access databases, so nothing SQL Server specific can be used, unless something equivalent exists as a substitute in the other two database systems.

Comment: Is `ID`not unique? Not clear for me why using `GROUP`

Comment: why not use simply `SELECT a.ID, a.ValueDate, a.Value FROM MyTable a WHERE a.Value > 0`?

Comment: anatol --- The ID and date column make up the unique key.  I use the GROUP BY because I want to gather data starting with the first non-zero value, but if after that if there is a zero value, I need to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see problem in redundant subquery, as I understood from your description. For example we have next rows in our table:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[ValueDate]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [MyTable]

ID  ValueDate                Value
1   2017-06-02 12:14:55.000  0
1   2017-07-02 12:14:55.000  0,1
1   2017-08-02 12:14:55.000  0,2
2   2017-08-02 12:14:55.000  0,2
```

So, your query gives next result:

```
ID  ValueDate                Value
1   2017-07-02 12:14:55.000  0,1
1   2017-08-02 12:14:55.000  0,2
2   2017-08-02 12:14:55.000  0,2
```

and it could be simplify to `SELECT a.ID, a.ValueDate, a.Value FROM MyTable a WHERE a.Value > 0` which gives same result.

Your subquery returns those rows only for join, so what is the reason to use it? I really don't understand why you use it.

Comment: This is time series data.  One value per month.  For cleanliness in graphing the data, I want to start with the month with the first non-zero value.  But after that I need every month, even those with a value of zero.  Thus, the subquery to find the month to start with that is the first month with a non-zero value.